# How would you design a variable current divider for non linear loads?

Tags: current, components, physics

What part or circuit would you put in the box in the center to be able to variably control the current between the two loads to smoothly dim between the two LED strings?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRnJYy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can you think of a way to do it without any inductors?

Can you think of a way to do it with high efficiency? (the sum of the load currents is approximately equal to the current supplied by the source)

Can you do it without PWMing between the loads? (Smooth current in, smooth current out)

Comment: Is this a homework question? Do all three requirements need to be met at the same time?

Comment: Nope! I need to design as circuit to do just this for a consumer light bulb. I have a few ideas of my own but wanted to see if the SE community had any ideas that might have a better combination of the requirements! Also just seems like an interesting made-you-think question. Sure made me think...

Comment: What sort of current levels are we talking about?

Comment: Just out of interest, why is the power source a constant current source?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast 100's of milliamps in my case

Comment: @Andyaka in my case because I'm doing an update to an existing product and and the existing power source is a CC buck converter. But I'm asking more generally to see how people would creatively solve the problem!

Comment: PWM is probably the best bet for smooth fading.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the simplest answer is: a rheostat.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHt4O9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

with a starting value as shown will provide operation, although the resistance will take a bit of tweaking depending on the exact extinction ratio you want. A smaller resistance will probably work just fine.

A wiper current of several hundred mA is too much for standard pots, but rheostats are designed for higher currents.

The circuit takes advantage of the exponential voltage/current relationship for LEDs, and in effect encourages one string to hog the source current while the other is starved.

If the circuit as shown is too sensitive, small resistors (~0.1 to 0.5 ohm, I guesstimate) can be inserted into each string.

Because the resistors involved are small I'd estimate pretty good (>90%) efficiency.